# representing parent-child relationship in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am facing problem regarding parent-child relations inside Excel, and is regarding display.

Suppose I have two tables 1 and 2 as follows,
[image: alt]
[image]

Now, what I exactly want is the following display which should be a concatenated result of both the tables
[image]

Please let me know if there exists any solution for the above, which is available from Excel and is Out of the box. I am sure this can be done using VBA, but I am basically looking out for a solution that should be more dependent on Excel Features.

Comment: Are there always exactly three foreign keys that correspond to one primary key? If so, it's probably possible do with formulas. If not, then I think VBA is the way to go.

Comment: I am sorry but that 's not the case, there could be more than 3 primary keys related to a single foreign key in the second table

Comment: Then I would probably guess it is not possible with formulas, or even if it is, it would be extremely complicated. This is because (if you want it formatted exactly as above), your formulas would have to take into account where the title rows are (since each individual table could be a variable number of rows) and additionally, you would have to have some major conditional formatting rules. I think VBA is your best bet here.